# How to make chrome extension with use .dll

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a dll with c#. Now, I will develop google chrome extension. I want to use this dll in my chrome extension. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

[Native Messaging - Google Offical Document](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)

Try this ? use stdin and stdout, you need a 'exe' file not a 'dll'

Comment: I tried native message but its extension. I need plug-in.

Comment: @MuratGücük You mean plug-in like something in chrome://plugins ?